# Neural network simulation error

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, keras, spyder

I apply the below described neural network using a training dataset "two4" which is also visible below. The dataset has 150370 rows.

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
import numpy
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
# fix random seed for reproducibility
seed = 7
numpy.random.seed(seed)

dataset = numpy.loadtxt("two4.csv", delimiter=",")
# split into input (X) and output (Y) variables
X = dataset[:,0:22]
scaler = StandardScaler()
X = scaler.fit_transform(X)
Y = dataset[:,22]
# split into 67% for train and 33% for test
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.33,random_state=seed)
# create model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(12, input_dim=22, init='uniform', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(12, init='uniform', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, init='uniform', activation='sigmoid'))
# Compile model
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
# Fit the model
model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data=(X_test,y_test), nb_epoch=30, batch_size=10)
```

[image]
After i execute the simulation, it breaks down all the time and the error i get looks like:

```
 30810/100747 [========>.....................]Traceback (most recent call last):.9989    

  File "<ipython-input-1-adb3fdf3bae0>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/Dimitris/Desktop/seventh experiment configuration/feedforward_net.py', wdir='C:/Users/Dimitris/Desktop/seventh experiment configuration')

  File "C:\Users\Dimitris\Anaconda2\envs\keras_env\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 714, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\Dimitris\Anaconda2\envs\keras_env\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 74, in execfile
    exec(compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec'), glob, loc)

  File "C:/Users/Dimitris/Desktop/seventh experiment configuration/feedforward_net.py", line 26, in <module>
    model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data=(X_test,y_test), nb_epoch=30, batch_size=10)

  File "C:\Users\Dimitris\Anaconda2\envs\keras_env\lib\site-packages\keras\models.py", line 432, in fit
    sample_weight=sample_weight)

  File "C:\Users\Dimitris\Anaconda2\envs\keras_env\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1106, in fit
    callback_metrics=callback_metrics)

  File "C:\Users\Dimitris\Anaconda2\envs\keras_env\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 830, in _fit_loop
    callbacks.on_batch_end(batch_index, batch_logs)

  File "C:\Users\Dimitris\Anaconda2\envs\keras_env\lib\site-packages\keras\callbacks.py", line 60, in on_batch_end
    callback.on_batch_end(batch, logs)

  File "C:\Users\Dimitris\Anaconda2\envs\keras_env\lib\site-packages\keras\callbacks.py", line 188, in on_batch_end
    self.progbar.update(self.seen, self.log_values)

  File "C:\Users\Dimitris\Anaconda2\envs\keras_env\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\generic_utils.py", line 119, in update
    sys.stdout.write(info)

  File "C:\Users\Dimitris\Anaconda2\envs\keras_env\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\iostream.py", line 317, in write
    self._buffer.write(string)

ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
```

Do you have any idea what  might cause the error?

Comment: It looks like the standard output buffer is closed for some reason. If you are executing the code in an IDE it might be that you are closing the console window or the IDE is doing some weirdness.

Comment: Try to run it outside of spyder, from a command window. Does the same problem happen?

Comment: Can'c actually run it outside spyder, since i have created a keras virtual environment within spyder in order to be able to simulate neural networks. Running this code from a cmd won't work, since the created virtual environment attached to spyder is essential for this code to run.

Comment: Try `verbose=0`.

Comment: @MarcinMożejko: i have tried your solution in multiple simulations and it appears to be working, but on the other hand the flunctuation of the accuracy value in every epoch is not visible. Any suggestions about how i could output it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem comes from sending to much data to `standard IO` port in Spyder. This closes it. Try to set:

```
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data=(X_test,y_test), nb_epoch=30, batch_size=10, verbose=0)
```

Now you could recover `epoch` metrics values from e.g.:

```
epoch_loss = history.history["loss"]
```

A `history.history` dict stores all training statistics saved each epoch.